# WiFi not working with bcmwl-kernel-source on MacBook Air

Tags: 20.04, wireless, macbook-air

From **Additional Drivers**, I enabled the `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver for BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter. I rebooted the computer. WiFi wasn't working. So I reinstalled `bcmwl-kernel-source` from command line. Still not working.

I'm using Ubuntu Cinnamon Remix 20.04.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command line, I had to install appropriate linux headers (with super user privileges):

`apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Then reinstall the driver (super user):

`apt reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

WiFi began to work instantly.